# Formidable Files uploads naming files issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, file-upload, formidable

I am trying to upload files from next js app (T3Stack) using formidable backend to upload multiple files inside a file named upload , its actually getting uploaded but I have 2 issues, that I want to upload that file inside upload folder but I am sending an email ( email is just a folder name that I want to create ) I want to check if that email folder created then proceed to upload these files inside that folder with the original name of the file but sadly Formidable is creating a new name that I cannot change here is the frontend code :

```
 const handleFileUpload = async (fileInput) => {
const files = fileInput.target.files;

const formData = new FormData();
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  formData.append("multiple-files", files[i]);
}
formData.append("email", user.email);

try {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/files", {body: formData})

  if (res.status === 200) {
    toast.success("Success");
  } else {
    toast.error("Failed");
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error uploading files:", error);
  toast.error("Failed to upload files");
}
};
```

and here is the backend code :

```
import { NextApiHandler } from "next";
import formidable from "formidable";
import path from "path";
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const readFile = (req: any): Promise<{ fields: formidable.Fields; files: formidable.Files }> => {
  const options: formidable.Options = {};
  options.uploadDir = path.join(process.cwd(), "/uploads");
  options.maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = formidable(options);

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve({ fields, files });
    });
  });
};


const handler: NextApiHandler = async (req, res) => {
  if(req.method === "POST"){
  try {

    // Create the 'uploads' folder if it doesn't exist
    await fs.mkdir(path.join(process.cwd(), "/uploads"), { recursive: true });
    // // Read files from the request
    const { fields, files } = await readFile(req);
    
    // Assuming you are handling multiple files, adjust accordingly if needed
    const fileDataArray = (files.image || []).map((file) => ({
      name: file.originalFilename, // Use the original filename
      size: file.size,
      path: `/uploads/${fields.email}/${file.newFilename}`,
      extension: file.extension,
    }));

    res.status(200).json({
      error: false,
      data: fileDataArray.map((fileData) => ({
        name: fileData.name,
        path: fileData.path,
      })),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing file upload:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: true, message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}
};

export default handler;
```